# Swift PHAsset image request issue

Tags: ios, swift, phasset

I'm having an issue when requesting `PHAsset/PHImageManager`

Initially I'm fetching the image assets via PHAsset.fetchAssets, appending them to an `UIImage` array and loading them into a `collectionView`. This works with no issues. The request image size is smaller enough to not cause any loading delays.

Next, when I select the `collectionView` cell in the `didSelectItemAt` delegate function, I'm attempting to re-request the `PHAsset`, with a larger image size (quality) and append the larger images into another `UIImage` array.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    /* Store the selected image into a variable */
    let selectedImage = images[indexPath.item]

    /* Request a larger quality image */
    if let index = self.images.index(of: selectedImage) {
        let selectedAsset = self.assets[index]

        let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()
        let targetSize = CGSize(width: 600, height: 600)

        imageManager.requestImage(for: selectedAsset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .default, options: nil) { (image, info) in

            if let image = image {
                self.selectedImages.append(image)
            }
        }
    }
print(selectedImages.count)
}
```

Two issues I'm facing:

1) when printing the count of the array, I get odd numbers (1, 3, 5, 7 etc) instead of the incremental count (1,2,3,4 etc). No idea why this is happening? Causing my 'selectedImages' array to increase abnormally.

2) This error occurs when selecting the 2nd cell (index 1) of the collectionView:

> 2019-02-12 21:12:40.029686-0800 ModularX[15837:4640133] [ImageManager]
>   FigPhotoDecompressionContainerDecodeImageForIndexAsync
>   -[PLFigPreheatItem startPreheatRequestWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke_2 returned
>   -16074 from /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/102APPLE/IMG_2427.JPG 2019-02-12 21:12:40.041596-0800 ModularX[15837:4640145] [ImageManager]
>   PFFigCreateCGImageFromImageData UIImage
>   *PLCreateImageFromDataWithFormat(NSData *, BOOL, PLPhotoImageFormatID, NSString *, BOOL, CFDictionaryRef *, NSDictionary *) returned -16074

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Anyone come across this?

Comment: Just following up to see if anyone has experienced this before